# Integrator key not showing/working in production

Tags: docusignapi

I have created application that sends docusign document to emails i specify in form.

**It's working fine in demo mode, without any error.**

I have also signed the integrator key to make it work in production(Live) account (However its not showing any integrator in admin area here).

It gives error this error in live mode **"The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled"**

**I have signed up using different email id for demo account then that is for production, but I have got approved my integrator key for production(Live) account.** is this might be a problem?

So what's the problem, do i need to do any thing more to the live account (Like adding the demo user, or something like that)?

How do i verify that they have made my integrator key available for production?

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I have also signed the integrator key to make it work in production(Live) account"?  What exactly did you do to make it work in the production account?

Comment: @ergin They have some kind of procedure to fill one form which takes your sandbox's integrator key, which they verifies and moves it to be used in production, (I have send them but still i didn't receive emails from them nor i can see them in my production panel).

Answer (score 0):

To make an integration key work in production you have to apply for it to be live. The Go-Live process was automated after this question was asked. https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-docusign-go-live-process-now-automated/ talks about these changes.